# postgreSQL how many subscriptions were bought each month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
Subscriptions (idsub, dstart, dend, #idk)
```

dstart is date when the subscription was bought (Data type: date)

I need to count how many subscriptions were bought each month this year (or preferably - chosen year).
I know It should probably be done with COUNT, however I just started learning SQL and I am struggling with the 'each month' part.

I am using Postgresql

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', dstart) as yyyymm COUNT(*) total
FROM Subscriptions
WHERE dstart >= DATE_TRUNC('year', now()) AND
      dstart < DATE_TRUNC('year', now()) + INTERVAL '1 YEAR'
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

The important component of this query is the `WHERE` clause.  Although it might look complicated, `dstart` is not the argument to a function.  That helps the optimizer and allows the optimizer to use an index on the column -- if one is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try to use this querry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dstart, 'MM/YYYY') date, COUNT(*) total
FROM Subscriptions
WHERE EXTRACT(year from dstart) = 2019 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dstart, 'MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Hardcoding 2019 is non-ideal. Eventually the future will come (in 35 days from this writing to be precise) and someone would have to manually update the year. A more future-proof alternative would be to replace 2019 with `EXTRACT(year from CURRENT_DATE)`.

Comment: He asked for a chosen year preferably, not just the current one

Comment: Also works, whowever you use multiple functions i do not know so I will stick to the Alex's one. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to apply `GROUP BY` so your `COUNT` will go by month. You mention that `dstart` is the starting date, so we will have to get the month from that. One way to accomplish that is with `date_trunc`. (The docs for `date_trunc` can be read here for more info on how it works: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html).

Finally, you can get the current year with `CURRENT_DATE` and use `date_trunc` again to only get subscriptions from this year.

All in all, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dstart),
    COUNT(idsub)
FROM Subscriptions
; to change the year, just change CURRENT_DATE 
; to a date with the year of your choice
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', dstart)=DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dstart)
```

There are other ways to do this exact thing, but this should solve your basic problem and be more than enough to get you started. From here, for example, you could also sort by number of subscriptions by adding `ORDER BY COUNT(idsub) DESC`.